# Unable To Locate And Select Item In Array

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm learning to use cypress.io and looking to learn JavaScript at the same time.

I'm currently looking to automate an internal application for work as a proof of concept as to why we should consider switching to cypress.io instead of Webdriver.

My current issue is that I have a collection of elements that I need to loop for that contains a certain string, and select this element.

My code correctly locates all elements (located with a class), but when I try and loop through the elements looking for the one with the specific string, I'm hitting a brick wall.

Code as follow -

```
//Selecting profiles
cy.get('.card')
    .each(($el) => {
        if ($el.contains() === profile) {
            cy.wrap($el).click();
        }
    })
```

The profile variable is passed into the function that this snippet is located in.

I'm looking at the cypress documentation for .each and .contains functions.

But when I run this code I get the exception saying

> TypeError: $el.contains is not a function

But looking at the cypress doc, I can attach funtions to the $el object.

```
.get('ul>li').each(($el, index, $list) => {
// $el is a wrapped jQuery element
if ($el.someMethod() === 'something') {
  // wrap this element so we can
  // use cypress commands on it
  cy.wrap($el).click()
} else {
  // do something else
}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.contains()` is a Cypress function. As the doc page says, `$el` is a jQuery-wrapped element and not a Cypress-wrapped element, so `.contains()` will not work on it.

That said, `.contains()` is used to filter a selection and will return a [chainer](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Chains-of-Commands), not a boolean or a string, so this particular way of using `.contains()` would not work in the first place. This is a side effect of how Cypress queues its commands - see [this doc page](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Asynchronous) for more info.

---

For what you're trying to do, I suggest taking advantage of the native jQuery element:

```
//Selecting profiles
cy.get('.card')
    .each(($el) => {
        if ($el.text() === profile) {
            cy.wrap($el).click();
        }
    })
```

Note: I'm assuming `profile` is a string. If it is not, this code may need to be modified.

Comment: Accepted Answer. Thank you. 

Once I've read you comment and gone back to the docs it all makes sense now.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)